# I want all unique array value together in one field from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, filter, distinct, unique-values

I am using MongoDB. and I have multiple fields in documents of one collection, which are color, style, keywords, shape, etc. and all data type is an Array. I want all the unique values of color, style, shape, keywords, etc. from all the documents.

Sample document as pr below

```
  "_id": "5de63ae0d88ea145cc7accb5",
  "id": "28011",
  "name": "BID 2",
  "slug": "bid-2",
  "description": "<p>Decorative details of graphic foliage interpreted in the latest colours such as black, pink, green and turquoise. The soft texture of the ceramic envelops with warmth even the coldest dish.</p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li>Dishwasher and microwave safe</li>",
  "price": "0.00",
  "keywords": [
    "Kitchen",
    "cook",
    "cooking",
    "kitchens",
    "pantry",
    "kitchen room",
    "room",
    "cookhouse",
    "cookery",
    "cuisine",
    "cook room",
    "food",
    "Crockery",
    "dishware",
    "dishes",
    "plates",
    "platters",
    "stoneware",
    "bone china",
    "porcelain",
    "earthenware",
    "ironstone",
    "plate",
    "dish",
    "small dish",
    "fruit dish",
    "fruit plate",
    "",
    "dessert plate"
  ],
  "Country": [
    "Italy"
  ],
  "Shape": [
    "Round"
  ],
  "Brand": [
    "Bitossi Home"
  ],
  "Materials": [
    "Ironstone"
  ],
  "Usage": [
    "Fruit Plate"
  ],
  "Color": [
    "Pink"
  ]
  }
}
```

I tried with $groupby. but it's giving me unique arrays in different arrays. I want result like below

```
{'color' : ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'white', 'gold'],
'shape' : ['round', 'square'],
'style' : [],
'keywords' : ['room', 'kitchen']}
```

Comment: Ask questions with sample data, and provide what you have tried so far

Comment: @sathish please check the revised question with example document and response sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done using [addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) and [reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)

The group brings all the values into a single document.

The reduce converts the array of arrays into array

```
db.dimen.aggregate( 
   [ 
      { 
         "$group":{ 
            "_id":0,
            Color:{ 
               $addToSet:'$Color'
            },
            Shape:{ 
               $addToSet:'$Shape'
            }
         }
      },
      { 
         $project:{ 
            "Color":{ 
               $reduce:{ 
                  input:"$Color",
                  initialValue:[ 

                  ],
                  in:{ 
                     $concatArrays:[ 
                        "$$value",
                        "$$this"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            "Shape":{ 
               $reduce:{ 
                  input:"$Shape",
                  initialValue:[ 

                  ],
                  in:{ 
                     $concatArrays:[ 
                        "$$value",
                        "$$this"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
);
```

Comment: I am getting the same value multiple times using this query. I want Color, Shape, etc. wise unique data.

Comment: never mind I updated $concatArray to $setUnion and working perfect for me. Thank you. @Sathish

Comment: It's not performing well with more then 5 lacks records. It takes around 6 seconds. Can you please help me to improve query performance?

Comment: can you try creating index on exact fields that you are querying

Comment: I already added indexes on all of them. But the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

here is [MongoPlay Around](https://mongoplayground.net/p/trhR8blRYmQ)

```
db.collection.aggregate([ {
                            $unwind: "$Color"
                          },
                          {
                            $unwind: "$Shape"
                          },
                          {
                            $group: {
                            _id: null,
                                color: {
                                    $addToSet: "$Color"
                                },
                                Shape: {
                                    $addToSet: "$Shape"
                                }
                           }
                         },
                         {
                           $project: {
                               _id: 0
                         }

                      ])
```

**OR You can  use this**
You can use Distinct for only getting unique values from defined field.

```
// syntax is..
             db.collection.distinct(fields,query)

// your query is..

db.collection.distinct(color,style,shape)
```